# Can't place an absolute positioned image at the left-bottom corner

Tags: css, positioning, absolute

I need to place a background pattern image at the absolute left-bottom corner of the page (using `position: absolute`), but instead the image keeps appearing way above the bottom.

This is how the left-bottom corner should look: https://i.ibb.co/d5RkRdX/desktop-design-monthly2.jpg
This is how it looks instead: https://i.ibb.co/3r3jvBr/image.png

Here's some of my HTML and CSS code - the relevant element has the class of "bg-bottom":

```
<div class="row" id="pricing">

  <div class="card">
    <h2 class="card-title">Basic</h2>
    <h1 class="row price-title">
      <span>$</span>
      <span class="price basic">19.99</span>
    </h1>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">500 GB Storage</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">2 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">Send up to 3 GB</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <button class="btn">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-middle">
    <h2 class="card-title">Professional</h2>
    <h1 class="row price-title">
      <span>$</span>
      <span class="price professional">24.99</span>
    </h1>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">1 TB Storage</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">5 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">Send up to 10 GB</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <button class="btn">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2 class="card-title">Master</h2>
    <h1 class="row price-title">
      <span>$</span>
      <span class="price master">39.99</span>
    </h1>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">2 TB Storage</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">10 Users Allowed</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <p class="text">Send up to 20 GB</p>
    <hr class="seperator" />
    <button class="btn">LEARN MORE</button>
  </div>

</div>

<img class="bg-bottom" src="images/bg-bottom.svg" alt="bottom background" />
```

```
.bg-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: try adding `top : 100%` to `.bg-bottom` class

Comment: Tried that and it works now, thanks.